# javascript files being cached inspite of changes

Tags: php, javascript, caching

```
<META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html;">
<META content="MSHTML 6.00.2900.3314" name=GENERATOR></HEAD>


<?php $current_time="D M j G:i:s"; ?>
<script language="javascript" src="JAVA/ClientSideScript.js?time=<?php echo date($current_time,time()); ?>"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="JAVA/valid_check.js?time=<?php echo date($current_time,time()); ?>"></script>
```

I have added the above code to prevent caching javascript files.
It looks to work fine when I view the source. But I get this message from other people that they dont see the timestamp when they view the source code.

Comment: Are you sure you uploaded your changes and that the page they are on (i.e. your updated page with the anti-caching manner) isn't cached itself?

Comment: It's not the JS file that's being cached then, it's your HTML page.

Comment: "But I get this message from other people that they dont see the timestamp when they view the source code." <-- so why not look at the *real* issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're suggesting that they see this

```
<script language="javascript" src="JAVA/ClientSideScript.js"></script>
```

without any remnants of your `?time=` additions, then they have likely cached the html file. either have them refresh via f5 key, or change the filename in all pages linking to that html file, forcing a fresh load.